# using SQL in javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, html

I'm currently having some problems trying to make an event calendar. I've created the calendar and I have the events stored in a sql table (I have their dates stored by their month, day, and year) (also, I'm using Python for the rest of the code). How do I go about getting the event names (just a string) inside their corresponding cells? I'm pretty new to this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The subject of the question is unclear : using SQL in javascript? Maybe you can clarify if your question is about SQL or about Javascript?
If you are using SQL it's on the server side. All your javascript is in the browser (client side). Unless you are running Nodejs, but you mentioned Python.

Comment: Wow, that code is out dated with IE4 reference.... JavaScrpt is not going to connect to your SQL db from the clientside. The python code should spit out the events and write it out in a ay you an access it with JavaScript

Comment: Please review my answer below, and upvote or mark as as accepted if it helped you in thinking through the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm pretty new to this so any help would be appreciated.

Generally speaking (without knowing anything about your server-side setup is like) the Python web framework would do a SQL query and interpolate the values into the html template, returning that back to the browser.

Another common approach is some javascript would load data from a REST API (again served up by some Python web framework) using ajax calls then render the results into the page.

Comment: Do you know of any good references that I could look at to get a better idea on how to do this?

Comment: Since you mentioned you are using Python, I would recommend looking at some web frameworks for that language, such as Django or Flask (there are others too). They will have a section about `templating` which should give examples of how to write data into the html page returned to the browser. Please do not forget to accept my answer if this has turned out to be beneficial info. Thanks